# Are those two equivalent mathematically speaking?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Starting from the action

$$S=-\frac{1}{4}\int{F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}d^4x}$$ (until here this is physics but my question is about the math) that is:

I got the following equation of motion solving for that:
$$\partial_{\mu}F^{\mu\nu}=0$$
but we usually know that starting from the action above, we should get
$d^\star F=0$ which I am not getting.

My question are $d^\star F$ and $\partial_{\mu}F^{\mu\nu}$ equivalent?

Comment: They are the same (might be up to a negative sign). See for example Jost's Riemannian geometry and geometric analysis (The chapter on harmonic forms, it's in p.87 if you are using third edition)

Comment: Crossposted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/207913/2451